# Configuration of log4j with Apache Flume

Tags: apache, log4j, flume

I am running a flume agent with a netcat source, file channel and mongodb sink, I want to configure log4j to work with the server as flume is running as a background process. My configuration file is in /opt/flume/conf/log4j.properties, Please let me know if log4j property file is getting included on flume start, And if it is so why flume.log is not getting created,

Here is the configuration given below

```
flume.root.logger=INFO,LOGFILE
flume.log.dir=/opt/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/logs
flume.log.file=flume.log

log4j.logger.org.apache.flume.lifecycle = INFO
log4j.logger.org.jboss = WARN
log4j.logger.org.mortbay = INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver = WARN
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop = INFO
log4j.rootLogger=${flume.root.logger}
log4j.appender.LOGFILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxFileSize=100MB
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.File=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.LOGFILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t]             (%C.%M:%L) %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.DAILY=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}
log4j.appender.DAILY.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${flume.log.dir}/${flume.log.file}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.DAILY.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%t]     (%C.%M:%L) %x - %m%n

log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d (%t) [%p - %l] %m%n
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing log directory from flume.log.dir=/opt/apache-flume-1.4.0-bin/logs to flume.log.dir=/var/log/flume-ng
and what is the location of your flume.conf file?